# iOS app installed form TestFlight behaves different from that is installed directed from Xcode

Tags: ios, swift

Recently I created a scientific calculator app, and everything was fine when I installed it from Xcode and tested it directly on my phone. However, after I installed the version that I distributed it through Testflight(it is exactly same as the one before), the app start crush every second time when an `IBOAction` is called(the sender is `UIPanGestureRecognizer`). Initially it shows `NSInvalidArgumentException`  message, and I find the line

```
if sender.state == .began
```

might cause the error.

However, after a few tests, it starts showing

```
"Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x6c43f8bb8e00)" (at the line "init(elementKeeper: ElementKeeper)")
```

instead of

```
NSInvalidArgumentException
```

I have no idea what is happening here. Someone please helps me, I will appreciate it.

```
public class ParentheseKeeper {
    private var leftParenthese: [Int]
    private var rightParenthese: [Int]

    // MARK:- Initialization
    init() {
        leftParenthese = []
        rightParenthese = []
    }

    init(elementKeeper: ElementKeeper) { //"Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x6c43f8bb8e00)" shows here
        leftParenthese = []
        rightParenthese = []
        for (i, element) in elementKeeper.getElements().enumerated() {
            if element == .LeftParenthese { addLeft(i) }
            else if element == .RightParenthese { addRight(i) }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, Did you try to run the app on your phone from Xcode using the Release build configuration? Is the app crashing?

Comment: Yes. At first, I change it to release and it crushes. Then I fixed the bug and the app behaves normal. However, when I distribute the app through Testflight, it crushes again...And then the reason was NSRangException instead of EXC_BAD_CODE and NSInvalidArgumentException....

Comment: [tag:CRUSH] is an acronym for Controlled Replication Under Scalable Hashing. It is the algorithm that drives the Ceph object storage environment.  it doesn't seem to apply here.  For the record, it's "Crash", not "Crush"